# How to delete locked app on MacOS (Catalina)

Tags: macos, terminal, rm

I'm trying to delete a locked app on Catalina. In recovery mode, I disabled SIP, restarted and gave Terminal Full Disk Access.

Tried this:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/Crashplan.app: Operation not permitted
```

And this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:~ xxxxxxxxxx$ cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Applications/
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:Applications xxxxxxxxxx$ rm Crashplan.app
rm: Crashplan.app: is a directory`
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should always first check if there's an uninstaller.
This is dependant usually on whether you just copied the App directly from a .dmg or you ran an actual install .pkg

Uninstaller is in `/Library/Application Support/CrashPlan/Uninstall.app` or `~/Library/Application Support/CrashPlan/Uninstall.app` depending on who it was installed for.

Ref: Code42 KB - [Uninstall the Code42 app](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/6/Get_started/Uninstall_the_Code42_app)

Comment: Thanks. Reinstalled it, then uninstalled it. It's gone now. But what I'd like to know is why it returned "Crashplan.app: is a directory" in Terminal. Would just like to understand why.

Comment: Because technically, all Apps are folders. Right click one & 'show package contents'